# Extra Line Breaks Detected with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, notepad

While I read my txt file in visual studio, its shows extra line breaks, but when I open same file with notepad it doesn't show those line breaks.

I am reading my file with System.IO.File

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myfile.txt")
```

How to read file without those unwanted linefeeds. 
Don't want to do replace `.replace("\r\n","")` since it will replace all genuine line feed as well.

EDit
Just Tried with NotePad++
With Notepad ++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmHbr.png)

Now with Normal Notepad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpWwW.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl "Why does it happen", I guess.

Comment: Can you show us these "extra line breaks"? For example, open this file in Notepad and show screenshots. Then, show the contents of `file` variable after reading - using screenshots or copy it here.

Comment: Perhaps the line breaks being shown by VS are `"\r"` or `"\n"` but not `"\r\n"` -- have you looked into that yet?

Comment: Open the file in notepad++, go to View > show symbol> show end of line. That should show you all line breaks. What you get from ReadAllLines() should be exactly that.

Comment: Please see my updated question with screen shots

Comment: @CreativeMind: Ok. Thanks. Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Notepad++ screenshot shows the problem very clearly. You have multiple line breaks at the end of certain lines.(Well blank lines in other words).

```
 var alllines =  File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  "myfile.txt")

 var validlines = alllines.Where(l=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(l));
```

now use validlines in your code instead of all lines

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to replace repeated new lines, the traditional (and lazy and wrong) way to do it is:

```
text=text.Replace("\r\n\r\n","\r\n");
```